# Communication between EKS Cluster Nodes and another EC2 instance running under LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

I have an EKS cluster running with 4 nodes. Application on these node calls service running on another EC2 instance via Route 53 -> LoadBalancer.
What should be idea way to configure security group in order have traffic flow EKS-Nodes -> Route 53 -> LoadBalancer -> EC2?

Comment: which port application is running on  ?

Comment: its running on 443

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your Load Balancer's security group (in case it's ALB or Classic LB) to allow port 443 from EKS node's security group.

If you're using NLB you should instead modify your application EC2 instances security group.

Comment: At LB I need to configure Cluster Security group or Additional Security group of EKS. And if it is Additional Security group do I need to configure any Ingress in Additional Security group ?

Comment: You need to take Node Security Group. This is a part of Node Group configuration. Alternatively you can go to EC2 console and manually see the worker nodes security group.